# Convert (transpose) dataframe lists to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has a list of values inside a cell. I need to convert these values into columns containing true or false if the column value is inside the list for that row. I need a column for every unique value inside every row's list.

This is my dataframe:

```
data = [
{"agency_id": 1,"province": ["CH", "PE"]},
{"agency_id": 3,"province": ["CH", "CS"]}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   agency_id                          province
0          1                  [CH, PE]
1          3                          [CH, CS]
```

To create the intial dataframe.

Then I tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['province'].values.tolist(),index=df['agency_id'])
```

and it outputs this:

```
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
agency_id                                                
1            CH    PE    AQ    TE  None  None  None  None
3            KR    CS  None  None  None  None  None  None
7            FE    FC    BO    MO    RA    RE    RN    PR
8          None  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
10           RM  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
11           RM  None  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

But it's not what I want because the columns are not "aligned".

I need something like this:

```
agency_id CH PE CS
1 true true false
3 true false true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up / modify your `data` if you do not like to import `from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{"agency_id": 1,"province": ["CH", "PE"]},
{"agency_id": 3,"province": ["CH", "CS"]}
]

# get all provinces from any included dictionaries of data:
all_prov = sorted(set( (x for y in [d["province"] for d in data] for x in y) ))

# add the missing key:values to your data's dicts:
for d in data:
    for p in all_prov:
        d[p] = p in d["province"]

print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
# data
[{'agency_id': 1, 'province': ['CH', 'PE'], 'CH': True, 'CS': False, 'PE': True}, 
 {'agency_id': 3, 'province': ['CH', 'CS'], 'CH': True, 'CS': True, 'PE': False}]

# df 
     CH     CS     PE  agency_id  province
0  True  False   True          1  [CH, PE]
1  True   True  False          3  [CH, CS]
```

Comment: Accepted because this was the most complete answer so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From `sklearn` `MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['province']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.agency_id).astype(bool)
Out[90]: 
             CH     CS     PE
agency_id                    
1          True  False   True
3          True   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, just using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
{"agency_id": 1,"province": ["CH", "PE"]},
{"agency_id": 3,"province": ["CH", "CS"]}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df['province'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x)).str.get_dummies().astype(bool).set_index(df.agency_id)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
             CH     CS     PE
agency_id                    
1          True  False   True
3          True   True  False
```